# Derivatives of morphisms of linear algebraic groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, group-schemes

I am currently trying to learn about linear algebraic groups and their lie algebra structure.

However, I am struggling to explicitly calculate the derivatives of morphisms between algebraic groups, as soon as they are not explicitly given by polynomial functions. (e.g. det: $GL_n \to G_m$ is clear for me as you can just differentiate and get the trace).

However, if you take e.g. quotient maps, I don't know how to find derivatives in a kind of "algorithmic" way.

Take for example Exercise 4.4.11(3) in Springer's book on Linear Algebraic groups. There, he gets the map $\varphi: SL_2 \to PSL_2$ by firstly taking the inclusion $SL_2 \to GL_2$ and then the quotient map $GL_2 \to GL_2/Z(GL_2)$. How would one go about calculating the derivative $d\varphi$ to show that it is an isomorphism in this case (for char(k) not 2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean I don't really think you *can* find them in an algorithmic way that doesn't require you giving a description of the map in coordinates. But, this is perhaps not that unexpected. We need something more abstract.

The following can be phrased more generally, with a slightly less desirable conclusion. But, this level of generality is maybe not really helpful for you right now. I am not sure what your background level is. Let me know if what I have written is not understandable.

> **Proposition:** Suppose that $$1\to K\to G\to Q\to 1$$ is a short exact sequence of smooth algebraic groups over $F$. Then, there is an exact sequence $$0\to T_e(K)\to T_e(G)\to T_e(Q)\to 0.$$

I am not sure what your background is, but let me try to clarify some things:

- here by 'algebraic group', I mean finite type affine group $F$-scheme,
- by smooth I mean in the sense of algebraic geometry but, for groups, this is equivalent to being geometrically reduced, equivalently reduced if $F$ is perfect, and actually it's automatic if $F$ has characteristic $0$,
- the exactness means that $K$ maps isomorphically to $\ker(G\to Q)$, and that $G\to Q$ is faithfully flat, and as $Q$ is smooth over $F$ this is equivalent to $G\to Q$ being surjective.

*Proof of Proposition:* As this question is entirely unchanged after base changing to $\overline{F}$, we may assume without loss of generality that $F$ is algebraically closed.

Recall that one way to define $T_e(H)$ is as $\ker(H(F[\varepsilon])\to H(F))$, where $F[\varepsilon]:=F[x]/(x^2)$ is the dual number, and $F[\varepsilon]\to F$ is the map sending $\varepsilon$ to $0$. Moreover, if $H$ is smooth over $F$ then we have that $H(F[\varepsilon])\to H(F)$ is actually surjective -- this is just the infinitesimal lifting criterion!

So, we get a map of exact sequences

$$\begin{matrix}1 & \to & K(F[\varepsilon]) & \to & G(F[\varepsilon]) & \to & Q(F[\varepsilon]) & \to & 1 \\ & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow  & & \\ 1 & \to & K(F) & \to & G(F) & \to & Q(F) & \to & 1\end{matrix}$$

where the rows are exact by the definition of exact sequence, except for exactness on the right. The fact that $G(F)\to Q(F)$ is surjective is clear. The fact that $G(F[\varepsilon])\to Q(F[\varepsilon])$ is surjective uses the smoothness of $K$. One way to say this is that $K$ being smooth actually implies that $G\to Q$ is smooth, and being smooth implies that that you can always lift a section after moving to an etale cover (if that means anything to you) -- but the connected etale covers of $F[\varepsilon]$ are just itself, so you can actually just lift the section.

So, from the Snake Lemma (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/53139) for why this makes sense here) we deduce that there is an exact sequence

$$1\to T_e(K)\to T_e(G)\to T_e(Q)\to \mathrm{coker}(Q(F[\varepsilon])\to Q(F)).$$

But, as $Q$ is smooth, the map $Q(F[\varepsilon])\to Q(F)$ is surjective, and so this last cokernel is trivial. $\blacksquare$

So, let's apply this in your situation. So, as you said, we will assume that $F$ does not have characteristic $2$. Then, we have the short exact sequence

$$1\to \mu_2\to \mathrm{SL}_2\to \mathrm{PSL}_2\to 1,$$

where $\mu_2$ is the second roots of unity, embedded diagonally in $\mathrm{SL}_2$. All the groups here are smooth over $F$ (we are using that $F$ does not have characteristic $2$ here to say that $\mu_2$ is smooth). So, by our proposition we get a short exact sequence

$$0\to T_e(\mu_2)\to T_e(\mathrm{SL}_2)\to T_e(\mathrm{PSL}_2)\to 0.$$

But, note that $T_e(\mu_2)$ is trivial. Namely, $\mu_2$ is a finite (and so 'discrete') group, and so has trivial tangent space. More concretely, the map

$$\{\pm 1\}=\mu_2(F[\varepsilon])\to \mu_2(F)=\{\pm 1\},$$

is injective, so the kernel is trivial. Thus, we deduce that $T_e(\mathrm{SL}_2)\to T_e(\mathrm{PSL}_2)$ is an isomorphism as you desired.

In fact, inspecting the proof shows that if $\varphi\colon G\to H$ is a smooth isogeny of smooth algebraic groups (i.e. $\varphi$ is surjective with finite smooth kernel), then $d\varphi$ is an isomorphism. The intuition for this is clear, as such smooth isogenies are like 'finite covering spaces', and so like 'local isomorphisms' -- so of course they induce isomorphisms on tangent spaces.

Answer (score 1):

**Question:**"However, if you take e.g. quotient maps, I don't know how to find derivatives in a kind of "algorithmic" way."

**Answer:** A "hint" on how to make an explicit and elementary calculation (I mentioned this in the comments but it was deleted).

Let $SL_2:=Spec(k[SL_2])$ and  $PSL_2:=Spec(k[PSL_2])$. You define $PSL_2:=SL_2/\mathbb{G}_m$. There is an action

$$\sigma^*: \mathbb{G}_m \times SL_2 \rightarrow SL_2$$

inducing the "coaction"

$$ \sigma: k[SL_2] \rightarrow k[\mathbb{G}_m]\otimes k[SL_2]$$

and the coordinate ring of $PSL_2$ is the ring of coinvariants: $k[PSL_2]:=k[SL_2]^{\sigma}$, where $k[SL_2]^{\sigma}$ is the ring of elements $x$ with $\sigma(x)=1 \otimes x$. The ring $k[PSL_2]$ is calculated in the Springer book.
Let $k[SL_2]:=k[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]/(D-1)$ where $D:=x_1x_4-x_2x_3$. There is a natural inclusion

$$i: k[PSL_2] \rightarrow k[SL_2]$$

and the ideal of the "identity" $e$ in $k[SL_2]$ is the ideal $I:=(x_1-1, x_2,x_3,x_4-1)$. You must calculate the inverse image maximal ideal $i^{-1}(I):=J$
and you get a canonical surjection

$$ j:J/J^2 \rightarrow I/I^2.$$

The dual map $j^*$ is the tangent map:

$$j^* :=d_e(\pi): T_e(SL_2) \rightarrow T_e(PSL_2).$$

Then you must calculate $d_e(\pi)$.

Hence you must understand what the coaction $\sigma$ is, calculate the invariant ring $k[PSL_2]:=k[SL_2]^{\sigma}$ and calculate the ideals $I,J$.

This gives an "algorithm":

1. Understand and calculate the invariant ring $k[SL_2]^{\sigma}$.
2. Calculate the ideals $I,J$
3. Calculate the map $J/J^2 \rightarrow I/I^2$ and the tangent map $d_e(\pi)$.